# Eliminating Data using Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that has details of one has the datetime of emailopened (emailopened) and the other link clicked (emailclicked)in the mail by a person. I am trying to bring the data in one table with emailopened and emailclicked.

```
| ID | EmailopenedDateTime|     | ID | EmailClickedDateTime  |
| 1  | 2019-07-02 22:05:26|     | 1  | 2019-07-02 22:05:41   |  
| 2  | 2019-07-03 22:44:14|
```

I tried using right join but I am getting output as

```
| ID | EmailopenedDateTime| EmailClickedDateTime  |
| 1  | 2019-07-02 22:05:26| 2019-07-02 22:05:41   |  
| 2  | 2019-07-03 22:44:14| 2019-07-02 22:05:41   |
```

```
Select 
         emailopened.id,
         emailclick.EmailClickedDateTime
         emailopened.EmailopenedDateTime
    from emailclicked emailclick
    right join
         emailopened  emailopened
    on
         emailclick.id = emailopened.id
```

But the output i am expecting is

```
| ID | EmailopenedDAteTime| EmailClickedDateTime  |
| 1  | 2019-07-02 22:05:26| 2019-07-02 22:05:41   |  
| 2  | 2019-07-03 22:44:14|         NULL          |
```

Would also appreciate if pyspark would be of any help.

Comment: Your query references `loannumber`, but it is not in the sample data.

Comment: Why aren't you joining on ID?

Comment: FWIW... not sure how the `clicked` vs `opened` is captured, but I would think that you can't have an `opened` without a `clicked`.

Comment: Sorry, The reference is on id. Thats my bad. Have edited the code.

Comment: yes, thats right. But, every time, a person opens a mail, need not mandatorily click on the link in the mail. Does that make sense?

Comment: `Select ID from emailclicked where ID = 2`  does that return a record? if so the problem is you have ID 2 in both tables and you're getting dates because records exist in both tables...

Comment: no i don't have id 2 in the clicked table. i checked that.

Comment: There must be more to your actual query or your actual data.  The output you're describing seems to be impossible from the query you've presented with the data you've presented.

Comment: Please do spell check before you post the question.  How do you expect people to help if the query and data don't match?

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense to Use LEFT OUTER JOIN with emailopened being the left table, considering your output (the left column is the one you are binding to while the right column with the NULL is not). Also, as a commentor stated, you are comparing apples with oranges in your question. You show ID being the key, but then state loannumber in your example query.

```
CREATE TABLE #a ( ID int, EmailOpenedDateTime DATETIME )
CREATE TABLE #b ( ID int, EmailClickedDateTime DATETIME )
INSERT INTO #a ( ID, EmailOpenedDateTime ) VALUES ( 1, '2019-07-02 22:05:26' ), ( 2, '2019-07-03 22:44:14' )
INSERT INTO #b ( ID, EmailClickedDateTime ) VALUES ( 1, '2019-07-02 22:05:41' )

Select 
  emailopened.id,
  emailopened.EmailopenedDateTime,
  emailclick.EmailClickedDateTime
from
  #a emailopened
  left join #b emailclick
    on emailclick.id = emailopened.id
```

Result:

```
id|    EmailopenedDateTime|   EmailClickedDateTime|
 1|2019-07-02 22:05:26.000|2019-07-02 22:05:41.000|
 2|2019-07-03 22:44:14.000|                   NULL|
```

Comment: This is what they already have written, they just used a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead. The issue is almost definitely that both records in `emailclicked` share the same `loannumber` with the corresponding records in `emailopened` as their actual results show. Jury's out though until they share enough sample data to verify.

Comment: Changing a right join to a left join doesn't change the output.

Comment: No, but it's more standard and I used ID for the join, not the loannumber that was in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If we literally put your data in as described:

```
DECLARE @emailopened TABLE (ID int, EmailopenedDateTime datetime)
INSERT INTO @emailopened VALUES (1, '2019-07-02 22:05:26'), (2, '2019-07-03 22:44:14')

DECLARE @emailclicked TABLE (ID int, EmailClickedDateTime datetime)
INSERT INTO @emailclicked VALUES (1, '2019-07-02 22:05:41')

Select 
         emailopened.id,
         emailclick.EmailClickedDateTime,
         emailopened.EmailopenedDateTime
    from @emailclicked emailclick
    right join
         @emailopened  emailopened
    on
         emailclick.id = emailopened.id
```

it produces this output:

```
id          EmailClickedDateTime    EmailopenedDateTime
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2019-07-02 22:05:41.000 2019-07-02 22:05:26.000
2           NULL                    2019-07-03 22:44:14.000
```

This is in-line with your provided data and expected output so that is the best we can offer for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

HIGHLY recommend going on images.google.com, search for 'SQL Join', and eyeball all of the pretty Venn diagrams between two sets that include the T-SQL to pull them off.  So far this is the best teaching tool I've seen in quickly understanding different table joins.

Good luck.